# ChilkatDotNet45.dll registration problems

Tags: chilkat

I keep getting the error:

The module "ChilkatDotNet45.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.

Make sure that the "ChilkatDotNet45.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Why are you trying to regsvr a .NET dll?  Are you trying to build a cargo ship out of bamboo?

Comment: The chilkat forum says that I need to in order to resolve build issues per this link:http://www.chilkatforum.com/questions/114/64bit-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-chilkatdotnet4-or-one-of-its-dependencies-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format

Comment: The accepted answer is probably correct.  Says nothing about regsvr.  This is .NET, not VB6/C++.  Unless the binary is exposing a COM interface you need, you do NOT have to regsvr it.  Period.  I'd ***strongly suggest*** that you [edit] and add details about the problem you are trying to solve.  And, while you're at it, change the title to match and add appropriate tags (like .net, the language, the IDE, etc)

Answer (score 1):

The ChilkatDotNet45.dll is a .NET assembly.  It is not an ActiveX DLL. There is no regsvr32 registration for .NET assemblies.